# Query for "surrounding hex tiles" based on axial coordinates

Tags: sql, algorithm

After reading Red Blob Games' excellent [article on heaxgon tile maps and their coordinates](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/).

I am wondering how one would write a SQL-query that returns the tiles surrounding a centered tile up to a range of X. (assuming the "axial coordinates" covered in the article)

A simple idea I first had was

```
WHERE x BETWEEN tile_x - 1 AND tile_x + 1 AND y BETWEEN tile_y - 1 AND tile_y + 1
```

But this will return too many tiles, in a way that creates a shape more like a rhombus rather than a circle, which is what I need.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a conclusive answer to this, maybe someone here can give me a hint.

I already thought about some tricks on the sum of the coordinates and wether they are larger of lower than the range, but this won't work with the axial coordinates.

Comment: Without investing any *real* thought into this, you need to add an additional test - "shares an edge with tile".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading, I found that the article I linked actually alread solves that problem, although somewhat hidden, so here is a more "straight forward" answer.

(Nonetheless, Terje D.'s answer works fine, I just post this because I feel it's a little easier to understand than the "sorcery" of his answer)

In the [article from Red Blob Games](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#neighbors), he actually describes the formula that calculates the distance between two given hexes:

```
function hex_distance(Hex(q1, r1), Hex(q2, r2)) {
    return (abs(q1 - q2) + abs(r1 - r2)
          + abs(q1 + r1 - q2 - r2)) / 2;
}
```

I translated this into a function in MySQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION `rangeBetweenTiles`(tile1q int, tile1r int, tile2q int, tile2r int) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN (abs(tile1q - tile2q) + abs(tile1r - tile2r) 
        + abs(tile1q + tile1r - tile2q - tile2r)) / 2;
END
```

And use this in another function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `isInRange`(tile1q int, tile1r int, tile2q int, tile2r int, `range` Int) RETURNS tinyint(1)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN rangeBetweenTiles(tile1q, tile1r, tile2q, tile2r) <= `range`;
END
```

Which can then be used very easily in a select statement:

```
select *
from tiles
where isInRange(:tile_q, :tile_r, positionQ, positionR, :n)
```

And it works perfectly fine for any `:n`

Answer (score 1):

From the diagrams in the linked article, it seems that something like

```
where (x between tile_x and tile_x + 1) and (y between tile_y - 1 and tile_y + 1)
or (x = tile_x - 1) and (y = tile_y)
```

should work

If you want to find the tiles `(tile_x, tile_y)` within a distance `n` from a given tile `(x, y)`, it will be easier if the x coordinate is modified by adding `0.5` to the `x` coordinate of each row having an odd distance from the given tile, such that the symmetry is increased:

```
       -1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5                                                   
      -2   -1   0   1   2                                                  
  -2.5 -1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5 2.5                                               
 -3   -2   -1   0   1   2   3                                              
  -2.5 -1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5 2.5                                               
      -2   -1   0   1   2                                                  
       -1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5
```

This can be achieved using the expression `tile_x + 0.5 * tile_y%2`

As the number of tiles within the given distance is reduced by one
from row to row, the limits of (modified) x coordinates in a given
row is `n - abs(tile_y - y)/2`.

Then the tiles is within a distance n if

```
abs(tile_y - y) <= n                                                       
and abs(tile_x - x + 0.5 * (tile_y-y)%2) <= n - abs(tile_y - y)/2
```

In sql:

```
SELECT tile_x, tile_y                                                      
FROM tiles                                                                 
WHERE ABS(tile_y - y) <= n                                                 
AND ABS(tile_x - x +0.5*(tile_y-y)%2) + ABS(tile_y - y) / 2 <= n
```

Comment: That works nicely for `n=1`, but when I try it for `n=2`, it gives me very odd results - the number of tiles returned is correct (19), but it also returns me, e.g. `(-2,-1)`, which if you look at the diagram, is not in the range of 2 aroung the center (0,0)

Comment: @Florian Peschka  As the diagram has the zeros in the odd numbered rows to the _right_ of the others, 0.5 should be _added_, not substracted. The answer is corrected accordingly.